# How do I add a background color spanning the browser width behind my navbar and in front of the background image

Tags: css, navbar, background-color

New to Bootstrap 3. Client wants the navbar color to span the browser window width, while keeping the actual navbar centered. Old CSS meant adding a background image to repeat, but I am using the Carousel background set to "cover" with a z-index -99. It seems it should be simple and a stacking issue.  I've tried putting this on the body tag inline, body css styling, I've tried recreating the navbar, but it left justified and I couldn't find the solution for that.  Any help would be appreciated. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdjQT.jpg)

```css
body {
 background-color: #0d4ea2;
}
.carousel { z-index: -99; } /* keeps this behind all content */
.carousel .item {
    position: fixed;
 width: 100%; 
 height: 100%;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s;
    -ms-transition: opacity 1s;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s;
    transition: opacity 1s;
}
.carousel .one {
    background-image: url(../images/auto-wheel.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
}
.carousel .two {
    background-image: url(../images/auto-snow.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
}
.carousel .three {
    background-image: url(../images/auto-sunset.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
}
.carousel .contactPg {
    background-image: url(../images/contact-mando-auto-parts.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
}
.carousel .active {
opacity: 1 !important;
}
.carousel .left {
opacity: 1 !important;
-webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s  !important;
-moz-transition: opacity 0.5s  !important;
-ms-transition: opacity 0.5s  !important;
-o-transition: opacity 0.5s  !important;
transition: opacity 0.5s  !important;
}
@media (max-width:767px) {
    #myCarousel {
        display:none !important;
    }
}
.navbar-custom {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #0d4ea2;
    text-align: center;
 border:0;
 font-size: 100%;
}
.navbar-header {
 padding-right: 5%;
}
```

```html
<body>

 <div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row"></div>
 </div>
<div class="container">
 <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
<div class="carousel-inner">
         <div class="active item one"></div>
        <div class="item two"></div>
        <div class="item three"></div>
</div>
</div>

 <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-custom">
  <div class="container-fluid"> 
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#defaultNavbar1"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></button>
      <a href="index.html"><img src="images/mando-logo.png" alt="Mando Auto Parts" /></a></div>
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="defaultNavbar1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="index.html">HOME<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.mandocatalog.com/" target="_blank">CATALOG</a></li>
         <li><a href="http://mandoautoparts.com/blog/" target="_blank">ANNOUNCEMENTS</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="mando-auto-part-products.html" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">PRODUCTS<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="mando-auto-part-products.html#abs">ABS Sensor</a></li>
            <li><a href="mando-auto-part-products.html#accomp">A/C Compressor</a></li>
            <li><a href="mando-auto-part-products.html#alternator">Alternators</a></li>
            <li><a href="mando-auto-part-products.html#brakebooster">Brake Boosters</a></li>
            <li><a href="mando-auto-part-products.html#calipers">Calipers</a></li>
            <li><a href="mando-auto-part-products.html#ignitioncoils">Ignition Coils</a></li>
            <li><a href="mando-auto-part-products.html#mastercylinder">Master Cyclinder</a></li>
            <li><a href="mando-auto-part-products.html#oxygen">Oxygen Sensor</a></li>
            <li><a href="mando-auto-part-products.html#steeringpump">Power Steering Pumps</a></li>
            <li><a href="mando-auto-part-products.html#rack">Rack and Pinion</a></li>
            <li><a href="mando-auto-part-products.html#shocks">Shocks and Struts</a></li>
            <li><a href="mando-auto-part-products.html#starter">Starters</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
       <li><a href="contact-mando-auto-parts.html">CONTACT</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse --> 
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid --> 
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `.container` class here or move **navbar** section outside the `.container`. You placed the **navbar** section inside `.container`

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <!-- carousel -->
        <!-- nav section -->
    </div>
</body>
```

Move the **navbar** section outside the **.container** div

```
     <body>
<!-- nav section --> move it outside container and add container instead of container-fluid inside the navbar

     <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-custom">
      <div class="container">
      </div>
    </nav>

            <div class="container">
                <!-- carousel -->
            </div>
        </body>
```

Hope this Works